# Two implementations of GARCH(1,1) yields equal coefficients but different residuals in R

Tags: residuals, garch, volatility-forecasting

I am currently working on my master thesis which investigates on the volatility of the GBP (EUR/GBP & GBP/USD) due to the Brexit announcements.

Therefore to do so, I use a GARCH(1,1) model with a dummy variable for a day with a "Brexit announcement". Furthermore, I will extend this research through the IT stat (Cusum test) in order to detect the structural break. For this last point, I need the residuals of my GARCH model.

However, here comes the problem.

I used two GARCH models, the first one has been realized without the `rugarch` package and here is the code;

```
garch(na.omit(GBPEURreturn, order=c(1,1)))
residuals(garch(na.omit(GBPEURreturn, order=c(1,1))))
```

The second one has been realized with the `rugarch` package and here is the code;

```
exchrate<-read_excel("....")
exchrate$ret_EURGBP=c(NA,100*diff(log(exchrate$EURGBP)))
names(exchrate)[6]<-"ReturnEURGBP
retureurgbp<-na.omit(exchrate$'ReturnEURGBP')
spec<-ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1), external regressors=NULL),mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,0), include.mean=FALSE, external regressors=NULL),start.pars=list(), fixed.pars=list()
spec
garch<-ugarchfit(spec=spec,data=returneurgbp, solver=hybrid)
garch
residuals(garch)
```

The coefficients are the same in the two GARCH model however the residuals are very different and I think that the problem comes from my second code because the residuals are perfectly equal to the returns in the dataset..

If someone could help me this would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the model equations for reference:
\begin{aligned} 
r_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= c \quad \text{(constant cond. mean)} \quad \text{or}\quad \mu_t = \varphi_1 r_{t-1} \quad \text{(AR(1))}\\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d.(0,1).
\end{aligned}
First, I wonder what library you took the `garch` function from; it is not available in the base R.
Now, there are several possible causes of the problem. Here are two:

1. There are two kinds of residuals: standardized ($\hat\varepsilon_t$) and raw ($\hat u_t$). Perhaps you are comparing the former to the latter?
2. Your conditional mean models are likely different.
   In your first implementation, I do not see a conditional mean specification, so it must be the default; this is likely either a constant (perhaps zero) or ARMA(1,1). If it is a constant equal to zero, then you would have $r_t=u_t$ or in other words, raw residuals equal to observations.
   Your second implementation has AR(1) conditional mean. Here, I would not expect residuals equal to observations because $r_t=\varphi_1 r_{t-1}+u_t$.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! Concerning the first garch model, it comes from tseries package. Then I have to calculate the standardized residuals, therefore, I will have to divide the raw residuals by the conditional variance. Nonetheless, in the first garch model (where I do not include any information concerning the mean specification) I have residuals different from the return. On the other hand, with the rugarch package and where I include a ARMA(1,1), the residuals equal the observation and this is my concern because I need the stand. residuals to continue

Comment: @AlexandreScivoletto, to be precise, standardized residuals are obtained by $u_t/\sigma_t$, not $u_t/\sigma_t^2$. It is difficult to comment on your first implementation not knowing what conditional mean the function defaults to; you would have to check the documentation. Regarding the second implementation, residuals equaling observations seems problematic as you have specified the conditional mean equation as AR(1). Perhaps there is a coding mistake? It seems `spec` is missing a closing parenthesis, perhaps there are some other problems. What coefficient estimates do you get from `rugarch`?

Comment: Regarding the coefficient estimates from rugarch: ar1=-0.881/ ma1=0.8917/omega=0.002/ alpha1=0.048/beta1=0.945. For the code, I am going to write it here below. The mistake would certainly originate from the code, I have no other explanations

Comment: I edited the question with the complete code. Many thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: @AlexandreScivoletto, I see that AR(1) and MA(1) coefficients nearly cancel out, so the residuals are almost equal to the original series. Therefore, it could make sense to try a conditional mean model without the AR(1) and MA(1) terms. The model should improve in terms of goodness of fit vs. complexity (as measured by AIC, BIC and the like).

Comment: Therefore, my code changed because now I insert mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0). Finally, my coefficients (omega, alpha and beta) do not change and the residuals neither, they are again equal to the observation.. Do I have to make another manipulation in the code in order to remove the effect of the AR(1) and MA(1)?

Comment: Furthermore, I have just read the tseries package documentation related to the garch model (my first garch) and in this package the conditional mean is not taken into account. This could explained why I have different residuals (and maybe the good ones in the first model?) Unfortunately, I really need to use the rugarch package due to the fact that after, I will introduce a dummy variable

Comment: @AlexandreScivoletto, In your first implementation (`tseries`), given the conditional mean model appears to be $\mu_t=0$, the only reason for observations not equaling residuals could be that the residuals are the standardized ones $\hat\varepsilon_t$ rather than the raw ones $\hat u_t$; if not, this is a puzzle to me. Check which ones you are actually retrieving. In your second implementation (`rugarch`), you should now see raw residuals equal to observations. If not, it is a puzzle to me.

Comment: Yes, when I apply the formula, the residuals are the same. That's perfect! Thank you very much.